# Umbilical points plus isometric surface exercise

Tags: differential-geometry

**EXERCISE**

> a)Show that there is not surface with first fundamental form:
>   $$ds^2=udu^2+vdv^2$$ that can be isometric with a circular cylinder
>
> b)Find the Umbilical points of the elliptical surface:$$\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{3^2}+\frac{z^2}{5^2}=1$$

**ATTEMPT**

From the first Fundamental Form, we have that:

$E=u, G=v , F=0$.

We know that the parametrization of the circular cylinder is $(acost,asint)$

How can I continue so to show that $$E_p=u=E_{f_p}, G_p=v=G_{f_p}, F_p=0=F_{f_p}?$$

b)I don't have any idea how to work in this section of the exercise.

We know that a point is umbilical when we have that :
$$FL-EM=GL-EN=GM-FN=0$$ or $$k=\frac{L}{E}=\frac{M}{F}=\frac{N}{G}$$

***Our professor has never shown us a problem like this in class so I don't know how to work in these types of exercise.***

I would very grateful if someone could help me with this, with any hint or a thorough solution and explanation!

**Thanks, in advance!**

Comment: For (b) you're going to have to compute the first and second fundamental forms. For (a) ask your professor if he means *locally isometric* or *globally isometric*. You can see that this metric is locally isometric to the usual flat metric on the plane, and the plane is, indeed, locally isometric to the cylinder.

Comment: @TedShifrin But how can I compute the first and second fundamental forms only with the given type of elliptical surface? And thanks for all your help!

Comment: This is an awful computation to do, but you can parametrize it by stretching spherical coordinates (just as you can parametrize an ellipse by starting with a circle and stretching it to get $(a\cos t,b\sin t)$).